# How to handle delete in microservice architecture?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, event-handling, microservices, domain-driven-design

I want to create a system for project management with task/issue/chat. This isn't anything commercial just for learning purposes. It is simplified description containing only things that are neccessary to present the problem.

First problem I had was how to add task using task service without asking project service everytime if user is a member of given project. I know that more beetwen services communications == more problems, more latency and generally AvoidBadTM. So I decided to use JWT for each microservice. User that want to add task with task service need to first ask Auth service: give me jwt for Task, projectX and include permissions. Auth would call Project service to verify if user is a member and generate proper JWT token. We still have communication beetwen services but it is a single call for a span of token lifetime instead of doing it every call to task service. Here comes the problem.

What if user is removed/banned from the project or project was deleted?
If task service doesn't care about projects - it only cares if JWT is valid so user can create task X for project id Y then how to prevent banned(from project) user from accessing this service? Also if project is deleted and project service emit an event to event bus "I deleted project X" then task service read this event and removes all tasks assigned to project X. But what to do when some user still has valid access token and he creates another task after the event was processed? Task service doesn't check if project still exists and in the result we have dangling task in a database.

My solution to this problem would be to store in task service database info about existing projects. Only ids, so memory/storage footprint is minimal. So when project service emits "Project deleted event", task service would not only clear all task with given projectId but also removes stored projectId so task creation is not possible. Is this a good approach? What about banned users? Another entry in database and event to subscribe to?

Comment: Projet ids in task service seems good to me. It follows DDD principles of aggregate relations. For the banned user why not using a similar technique by keeping track of active users in the task/project service. Just rename user with a more appropriate name e.g. project manager to align with DDD bounded context rule.

Answer (score 1):

> My solution to this problem would be to store in task service database info about existing projects. Only ids, so memory/storage footprint is minimal. So when project service emits "Project deleted event", task service would not only clear all task with given projectId but also removes stored projectId so task creation is not possible. Is this a good approach?

Absolutely, the task should be aware of what project it belongs to so I don't see anything wrong with that - it makes sense.

> What about banned users? Another entry in database and event to subscribe to?

You mentioned that "Auth would call Project service to verify if user is a member and generate proper JWT token" so the outcome should be that Project Service should say that the user is not a member of the project. Now in your system you'd probably have `users` service that would have an API to ban the user. What I believe should happen is the following:

- In `projects` service you have a table called `members` that has a `N to N` relationship between a `user_id` and `project_id`
- When admin (not sure how the banning process is gonna work in your system) wants to ban the user, it'd call an API in `users` service
- `users` service will emit an event saying that `user 1 was banned`
- `projects` service will listen to this event and remove the records of this `user_id` from `members` table